# Is it possible to link a structured table filter to a cell value?

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I have a rather large table of persons' details, so most entries are text based, I wanted to be able to return rows of values based on an approximate search criteria, i.e. if I type `Jo` I'd like to see all entries like John, Jonnathan...etc.

I tried the index and match using `=INDEX(array,MATCH(lookUpValue,lookUpArray,-1),column)` or `1`, but doesn't return all values that are approximate; it simply returns a single value at a greater than/less than range of what was entered.

Instead, simply typing in the approximate search in the filter of the structured table column works as desired. So is it possible to link the filter search box to a cell where I can type my approximate search?

Comment: Table filters cannot be dynamic (when formatted as a table in excel)

Comment: That is a shame, is there an alternative? Surely I am not the first to have this issue

Comment: Convert your table back to a range

Comment: Advanced filter?

Comment: Advanced filter seems to be a way forward with some VBA. I will investigate and write back once I have found a suitable method!

Comment: Appreciate if you can share some sample data/screenshot for the case you are working on.. (: